# Creating a TreeView from the Model level

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `TreeView` in my program that needs to be implemented from the Data Model level of an MVVM structure. It needs to be implemented this way so that the program saves it in data. My program switches between different windows and the tree is lost during those switches if it only goes as deep as the View Model level. I have the data working, but the view does not reciprocate (a problem that I seem to be having a lot lately).

I will post my process here. Please keep in mind the structure of this `TreeView`:

> -Usercontrol(contains TreeView)->ViewModel->Model(TreeView needs to be stored in this Model)
>
> -TreeView->ViewModel->Model

**UserControl Model:**

```
public BlockingTreeViewModel _blockDataTree;

public BlockingDatabaseModel() { }

public BlockingTreeViewModel BlockDataTree {...}
```

**UserControl View Model:**

```
public BlockingDatabaseModel _blockingModel;

public BlockingDatabaseViewModel(BlockingDatabaseModel model, BlockingTreeViewModel blockingTreeView)
{
    BlockingModel = model;
    BlockingModel.BlockDataTree = blockingTreeView;
}

public BlockingDatabaseModel BlockingModel {...}
public BlockingTreeViewModel BlockingTree //PROXY PROPERTY
{
    get { return BlockingModel.BlockDataTree; }
    set
    {
        BlockingModel.BlockDataTree = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => BlockingTree);
    }
}
```

**UserControl.xaml:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding BlockingModel.BlockDataTree.BlockTree}" ... />
```

Now, upon adding to this `TreeView` I can see the new node when I debug, but the View does not show any newly created node. As far as my understanding of this situation, this is implemented correctly and should work fine. Please help me with why the view will not show this tree inside the UserControl.

**Now that the above changes have been applied to my xaml the tree nodes are created and displayed. However, these nodes disappear whenever I change the screen. This means that there is still something wrong with my `TreeView` in this MVVM structure.**

*Note: The property for the `TreeView` is a proxy property only because it makes my code simpler in other areas of my program. This should not affect what I am doing though.

**Update 1:**

Screenshot of my "Locals" window during debugging. This shows that I am able to create a new node in the `TreeView`.

[image]

**Update 2:** Updated bindings in xaml

Comment: You shouldn't store UI controls anywhere. Instead, define a class with a collection property of its own (or any) type (so that it can have children). In this way, you can `Bind` one (or more) of these objects to your `TreeView` *and save the object(s) instead*.

Comment: I'm not sure if I exactly follow. I'm not storing the control, I'm storing the ViewModel of the `TreeView`. The `ItemsSource` is then bound to it. Isn't this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Normally, you will bind collections (preferably `ObservableCollection`) to `ItemsSource` property. Your `BlockingTree` property doesnt seem to be a collection. If the collection is nested somewhere, you might then want to update your Binding, like say, `<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding BlockingTree.BlockDataTree.BlockTree}" />`

Comment: Okay, that works. However, now I experience the problem that I stated earlier: the node disappears upon changing the screen. Why would this happen now that my `TreeView` is implemented at the Data Model level?

Comment: Do you still have data in your ViewModels after changing the Screen? Also, where are you instantiating your ViewModel?

Comment: I believe that the ViewModel is reset to a new ViewModel every time the screen changes. Note that I do this in other areas of my program and it works fine. The ViewModel is instantiated in the MainWindow's View Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are switching screens that contain `TreeViews` you shouldn't create a new `ObservableCollection` every time you view the `TreeView` because it will reset the current one.

I say this because I was creating a new `ObservableCollection` in the ViewModel of my `TreeView` everytime I switched back to it.

constructor of my `TreeViewViewModel`:

```
public BlockingTreeViewModel()
{
    BlockTree = new ObservableCollection<BlockingTreeModel>();
}
```

Instead...:

```
//Pass the ObservableCollection from a different area of your code each time
//you use BlockingTreeViewModel so that you don't overwrite it.
public BlockingTreeViewModel(ObservableCollection<BlockingTreeModel> treeCollection)
{
    BlockTree = treeCollection;
}
```